# Xubuntu 16.04.2 - Terminal clear command

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

After the clear command, the following character appears. How can I fix this problem?

[image: Click to see the screenshot]

Terminal: xfce4-terminal 0.6.3

Comment: please close and restart your terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a alias to `clear` like

```
alias clear='printf "\033c"'
```

This works on my Ubuntu gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly without some more info but here are some things to check/try.

First, go to

```
Edit > Preferences > Advanced Tab > Encoding
```

and check the `Default character encoding` (mine is UTF-8, you may want to try ISO-8859-1 and see if that works)

If that doesn't help, try running the following:

```
$ echo $TERM
```

if you get back something other than xterm, run:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

and try again.  If that takes care of it you'll need to look into what is setting the TERM variable incorrectly: I'd start by looking in `~/.bashrc`

If, however `TERM` is set correctly, you can run the following to see what `clear` is actually sending:

```
$ clear | od -bc
```

and compare your output to mine:

```
$ clear | od -bc
0000000 033 133 063 073 112 033 133 110 033 133 062 112
        033   [   3   ;   J 033   [   H 033   [   2   J
0000014
```

if they match you may want try clicking the `Reset compatibility options to defaults` button in `Preferences > Compatibility tab`.

Hope that helps

Comment: I tested all of them, he said. As negative as the result.. :(

Comment: glad the alias above worked for you as a workaround, however I'm still curious - was your TERM set to xterm?  and did your clear command output the same as mine?